# Log4j ThreadContext from child thread

Tags: java, log4j2, threadcontext

I'm using with Log4J2 and ThreadContext and basically, I want the ThreadContext shared across all threads (or an alternative to ThreadContext, as the name seems to imply it should be thread-specific).

Right now I have both of these flags set in my programs arguments (added both, although I think the 2nd legacy):

```
-Dlog4j2.isThreadContextMapInheritable=true
-DisThreadContextMapInheritable=true
```

If, when my application first starts up, I do:

```
ThreadContext.put("key", "value");
```

The logs both in my parent thread and child thread will both output "value", so I am assuming the ThreadContext is successfully shared between the threads.

However, if I update that message just before my child runs with:

```
ThreadContext.put("key", "anotherValue");
```

My child thread still has the original "value", but the next message on the parent thread will be "anotherValue".

Same thing happens if I update the value in my child thread. The child thread will output "anotherValue" but the parent thread will still output "value".

I'm assuming I am missing something crucial about how the ThreadContext works, as what is happening makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [`ThreadContext`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.19.0/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/ThreadContext.html) explicitly states:

> **The MDC is managed on a per thread basis**. To enable automatic inheritance of *copies* of the MDC to newly created threads, enable the "isThreadContextMapInheritable" Log4j system property.

Even when you enable isThreadContextMapInheritable the `ThreadContext` is not shared - the child thread receives a copy, if you change either the parents `ThreadContext` or the childs `ThreadContext` they will diverge.

---

The log4j2 manual has the following hints that may help you in implementing your required functionality:

[Custom context data injectors](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html#Custom_context_data_injectors_for_non_thread-local_context_data)

> Log4j 2.7 adds a flexible mechanism to tag logging statements with context data coming from other sources than the ThreadContext. See the manual page on extending Log4j for details.

The manual page on [extending Log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#ContextDataProvider) contains some hints that you can implement the `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.ContextDataProvider` and register it as additional context data provider.

I myself have no experience in implementing such a `ContextDataProvider`.

Comment: Ah the old "RFTM fool"... I've been on that page a dozen times today and I don't know how missed the "copies" every time. Thanks! I'll also check out the ContextDataProvider, it looks like exactly what I need!